# How to use python sshtunnel with password instead of key file

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I want to open an ssh tunnel from my local machine to connect my python script to a remote database.
The code I use to open the ssh tunnel is:

```
        with sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
                (ssh_host, ssh_port),
                ssh_username=ssh_user,
                ssh_password=ssh_password,
                remote_bind_address=(db_ip, db_port)
        ) as tunnel:
            # dummy code to check tunnel
            tunnel.start()
            logger.debug(f"IsUp: {tunnel.tunnel_is_up} | {tunnel.local_bind_address}")
```

What I expected this to do (from various sources doing the exact same thing) was to open an ssh tunnel using the ss_user and ssh_password as credentials. (Yes the credentials are working when I manually ssh to the server in the shell)

What I get is a prompt from my local system (Ubuntu 20.04) to unlock my personal ssh key even though, I explicitly configured SSHTunnelForwarder to use a password instead.

The error message I then get is that the ssh tunnel could not be established because the authentication with the ssh key failed:

```
2021-11-23 08:40:10,847| ERROR   | Password is required for key <redacted path>/.ssh/id_rsa
2021-11-23 08:46:25,737| ERROR   | Exception: key cannot be used for signing
2021-11-23 08:46:25,786| ERROR   | Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-11-23 08:46:25,786| ERROR   |   File "<redacted path>/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2109, in run
2021-11-23 08:46:25,786| ERROR   |     handler(self.auth_handler, m)
2021-11-23 08:46:25,786| ERROR   |   File "<redacted path>/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paramiko/auth_handler.py", line 298, in _parse_service_accept
2021-11-23 08:46:25,786| ERROR   |     sig = self.private_key.sign_ssh_data(blob)
2021-11-23 08:46:25,786| ERROR   |   File "<redacted path>/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paramiko/agent.py", line 418, in sign_ssh_data
2021-11-23 08:46:25,787| ERROR   |     raise SSHException("key cannot be used for signing")
2021-11-23 08:46:25,787| ERROR   | paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: key cannot be used for signing
2021-11-23 08:46:25,787| ERROR   | 
2021-11-23 08:46:25,787| ERROR   | Could not connect to gateway <ssh_host>:<ssh_port> : key cannot be used for signing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<redacted path>/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sshtunnel.py", line 1608, in __enter__
    self.start()
  File "<redacted path>/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sshtunnel.py", line 1331, in start
    self._raise(BaseSSHTunnelForwarderError,
  File "<redacted path>/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sshtunnel.py", line 1174, in _raise
    raise exception(reason)
sshtunnel.BaseSSHTunnelForwarderError: Could not establish session to SSH gateway
python-BaseException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Somehow sshtunnel is by default trying to load any ssh key in the standard .ssh path instead of using the credentials provided.
Is this a bug in the version of the lib?
Im using

```
paramiko==2.8.0
sshtunnel==0.4.0
```

Or do I have to change my setup?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, does changing `sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(...)` to `sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(..., allow_agent=False)` help ?

Comment: Indeed, this produces the expected behavior! Thank you very much!
Up till now my only workaround was to (temporary) clear my .ssh folder...
I feel like this should be better documented somehow...
If you post your solution as an answer I will gladly accept it @manaclan

Comment: Hi, glad it help. It's actually cost me sometimes to find the documents and messing around. I posted an answer so this question can be closed, anw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [document](https://sshtunnel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=connect#sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder), setting `allow_agent` to `False` will help you `Enable/disable load of keys from an SSH agent`. For example:
`sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(..., allow_agent=False)`